# Existence of infimum (of distance between a point and a set)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Statement of what is to be proven: Let $C$ be nonempty and convex. Then any $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ has a unique closest point $P_c(x) \in \text{ cl} C$, called the projection of $x$ on cl$C$ ...(second half of lemma omitted)

The proof because with the statement:
"Let $\delta = \inf \{\|x-y\|\mid y\in C\}\geq 0$

If the infimum does not exist then we have a problem. I'm assuming that this is a non-issue since distance (at least euclidean distance) cannot be negative, $0$ is a lower bound?

Restated: Infimum can always be taken of a euclidean norm (distance), because it cannot be $<0$, correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\|\cdot\| \geq 0$, the set is bounded below, so the infimum exists and  will also be nonnegative.